# Formula for $P(X_1=a_1,\ldots , X_n=a_n)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For 1 discrete random variable, $$P(X= a)=P(X\le a)-P(x<a).$$
For 2 discrete random variables, $$P(X=a,Y=b)=P(X\le a,Y\le b)-P(X<a,Y\le b)-P(X\le a,Y< b)+P(X<a,Y<b).$$

What is the analogue for $n$ discrete random variables? The first two formulas can be explained graphically, but I cannot visualize the $n$-dimensional case.

Comment: The first formula should be $P(X=a) = P(X \le a) - P(X < a)$, unless you suppose that $X$ is integer valued an $a$ is an integer for example. Discrete does not mean integer valued.

Comment: The sign of last term in the second formula is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let $E_k=\{X_k=a_k\}, T_k=\{X_k\leq a_k\}, S_k=\{X_k<a_k\}$, so that $E_k=T_k\setminus S_k$ then:

$$\mathsf P(E_1,\ldots,E_n)~{=\mathsf P(E_1,\ldots, E_{n-1}, T_n)-\mathsf P(E_1,\ldots, E_{n-1}, S_n)\\~\\={\mathsf P(E_1,\ldots, E_{n-2},T_{n-1},T_n)\\-\mathsf P(E_1,\ldots, E_{n-2},T_{n-1},S_n)-\mathsf P(E_1,\ldots, E_{n-2},S_{n-1},T_n)\\+\mathsf P(E_1,\ldots, E_{n-2},S_{n-1},S_n)}\\\vdots\\ ={\mathsf P(T_1,\ldots, T_n)\\-\mathsf P(T_1,\ldots, T_{n-1},S_n)-\mathsf P(T_1,\ldots,T_{n-2},S_{n-1},T_n)-\ldots-\mathsf P(S_1,T_2,\ldots,T_n)\\+\ldots\\\vdots\\+(-1)^n \mathsf P(S_1,\ldots,S_n)}}$$

Well, you get the idea. For each $k\in\{0,..,n\}$, the series will contain $\binom nk$ terms which are the joint probabilities of the distinct selections of $k$ strict inequality events and $n-k$ non-strict inequality events, and the coefficients of these terms will be $(-1)^k$.

---

So for example:

${\mathsf P(X_1=a_1,X_2=a_2, X_3=a_3) ~}{= \mathsf P(E_1,E_2,E_3) \\ ={\mathsf P(T_1,T_2,T_3)\\-\mathsf P(T_1,T_2,S_3)-\mathsf P(T_1,S_2,T_3)-\mathsf P(S_1,T_2,T_3)\\+\mathsf P(T_1,S_2,S_3)+\mathsf P(S_1,T_2,S_3)+\mathsf P(S_1,S_2,T_3)\\-\mathsf P(S_1,S_2,S_3)}\\ ={\mathsf P(X_1\leq a_1,X_2\leq a_2,X_3\leq a_3)\\-\mathsf P(X_1\leq a_1,X_2\leq a_2,X_3\lt a_3)-\mathsf P(X_1\leq a_1,X_2\lt a_2,X_3\leq a_3)-\mathsf P(X_1\lt a_1,X_2\leq a_2,X_3\leq a_3)\\+\mathsf P(X_1\leq a_1,X_2\lt a_2,X_3\lt a_3)+\mathsf P(X_1\lt a_1,X_2\leq a_2,X_3\lt a_3)+\mathsf P(X_1\lt a_1,X_2\lt a_2,X_3\leq a_3)\\-\mathsf P(X_1\lt a_1,X_2\lt a_2,X_3\lt a_3)}}$